# need oauth 2 client implementation for react router

Tags: javascript, oauth, react-router

we have created our own oauth 2 server with authorization code implementation from below code base.
https://github.com/FrankHassanabad/Oauth2orizeRecipes

but we are trying to integrate oauth2 client authentication in web application which includes react router and flux implementation.

we looked into many git repositories but not getting any proper way to do this.

is there any implementation which points us to how it can be achieved?

Thanks again.

**UPDATE**

we are looking into below repositories, but still not clear on how we make things work. like where to merge auth and oauth logic and what things to make server/client side.

https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-flow

https://github.com/andreareginato/simple-oauth2

https://github.com/LearnBoost/superagent-oauth

https://github.com/zalando/superagent-oauth2-client

Comment: !! I see the below answer is more of methodology of protecting the routes after Oauth is completed. I am building an serverless react app, where I am handling all Oauth in react side itself. In fact, handling the Oauth in client or in server is subjected to debatable!! I have already handled the authentication of google in reactJS. But trying to authenticate the developer provided(I mean the own authentication system, unlike the socialOauths). I could not find any react client which does custom Oauth. I am sure gola would have handled it now. Let me know the flow or any repos in react

Comment: we used https://github.com/zalando/oauth2-client-js

Answer (score 39):

I'll attempt to explain my high level take authentication with react-router. You will need implementation on both server and client and there are a few decisions you need to make yourself. For this example I will be using [redux](http://redux.js.org/) for the flux library.

First you will need a mechanism to protect your routes, I do this with a higher order component like so:

```
// 'Components/requireAuthentication'

import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import SignIn from './SignIn'

export default (ChildComponent) => {
  class AuthenticatedComponent extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
      hasAuthToken: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
    };

    render () {
      const { hasAuthToken } = this.props
      return (hasAuthToken
        ? <ChildComponent {...this.props} />
        : <SignIn />
      )
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = ({session}) => (session)

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthenticatedComponent)
}
```

The code here is quite simple, it exports a function that expects a react component as the only argument. This `ChildComponent` is the component you want to protect.

The `hasAuthToken` prop is the control here, if it is true then the `ChildComponent` will be rendered, otherwise it will render `SignIn`. Note, this process of rendering `SignIn` is fine if you don't care about SEO but you may want to [redirect](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/API.md#replacestatestate-pathname-query) the user to a sign-in route if you do care about search engines indexing your protected routes.

Finally `AuthenticatedComponent` is connected to the redux store `session` state but this could easily be switched out to use any other flux library of your choosing. Simply put, it is subscribing to changes on `session`. If the `hasAuthToken` changes in value, the component will be re-rendered if it is presently mounted.

Now for the routes:

```
import { Route } from 'react-router'
import Container from './Components/Container'
import Private from './Components/Private'
import requireAuthentication from './Components/requireAuthentication'

export default (
  <Route path='/' component={Container}>
    <Route path='private' component={requireAuthentication(Private)}>
      <Route path='other' component={...} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
)
```

Here I am applying the `requireAuthentication` method (the default exported method from the code above) with the component I want to protect. This will keep pages from being shown unless the redux store `session.hasAuthToken` property is true and instead show the `SignIn` component.

Other routes nested under the protected component will also be protected because of the way react-router composes the routes.

At a high level the `SignIn` component should simply be a page with a normal `<a href>` (i.e. not react-router `Link`) to begin the Oauth2 handshake. The [simple-oauth2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-oauth2) module has some nice examples on how to implement oauth2 server-side so I won't get into that here. If you're following those examples, it's the `app.get('/auth', function (req, res) {})` endpoint you want to link the user to.

In the `callback` endpoint you will want to persist the `token` somehow (e.g. to your session ([express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) will help out here) or to the database), then redirect the user back to your react app.

Now you'll need to get your session into the server-side redux store in preparation for it to be hydrated on the client. The redux docs explains how to do this on the [Server Rendering](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html) page, specifically the [Inject Initial Component HTML and State](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html#inject-initial-component-html-and-state) and [The Client Side](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html#the-client-side) sections. At a minimum you'll need an object like this:

```
{
  hasAuthToken: (typeof req.session.token !== 'undefined')
}
```

Of course your actual implementation will depend entirely on how you store the token and provide it to the server-side request.

Hopefully this will get you started. This same process can be used for other kinds of authentication as well by replacing the Oauth2 link with a username and password form that your server handles as an XHR.

Best of luck.

Comment: You Marc - are a champion